# VBA conflicting sheet name checking via an IF function

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

I have two subroutines that seem to conflict one with each other. Each one of them is for creating and formatting a new worksheet if it doesn't already exist and I ran into a problem where I can only create one of them and not the other (whichever one is the first one I call to create). I found taht it seems to skip the end sub function in an if function:

```
    For Each Worksheet In Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        
    If Worksheet.Name = "Machine Layout" Then
    Exit Sub
    
    Else:
    Sheets.Add.Name = "Machine Layout"
    End If
    Next
```

And gives an error that sheet with such name already exists.

Both subroutines use this same code except the worksheet name changes.

I'm wondering what's teh problem with that? Could someone, please, help?

Comment: Why do you loop to create a sheet? It will try to create it based on the number of sheet you have. If you have 4, it will try to create it 4 times with the same name - hence the error.

Comment: Your code would look at each sheet, but for each sheet it asks "is this one called 'Machine Layout'" - if it isn't it will create it.  It then moves onto the next sheet and asks again - if it isn't it will try and create it, but the first loop has already created it.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Logic is wrong.

```
set wb = ActiveWorkbook
For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "Machine Layout" Then Exit Sub
next ws

Sheets.Add.Name = "Machine Layout"
```

I did not test my answer...